# Emacs Lisp: Wrong number of arguments function with user input calling it in add-hook

Tags: debugging, emacs, hook

I'm basically trying to give the user the option to save the current session using perspective before closing emacs.

```lisp
(defun save-current-session (yes-or-no-bool)
  (interactive
   (list
    (y-or-n-p "Do you want to save this session for later? ")))
  (if yes-or-no-bool
      (persp-state-save "~/.emacs.d/persp-state-file")))
```

This function asks the user if he/she really wants to save the current session. Calling this function using M-x gives the desired outcome. I get asked if I want to, yes or no and if I type "y" it successfully saves it, but as I add it to kill-emacs-hook like that:

```lisp
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'save-current-session)
```

I get this error:

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (yes-or-no-bool) (interactive (list (y-or-n-p "Do you want to save this session for later? "))) (if yes-or-no-bool (persp-state-save "~/.emacs.d/persp-state-file"))) 0)
  save-current-session()
  kill-emacs()
  save-buffers-kill-emacs()
  evil-quit(nil)
  funcall-interactively(evil-quit nil)
  call-interactively(evil-quit)
  evil-ex-call-command(nil #("q" 0 1 (ex-index 1)) nil)
  eval((evil-ex-call-command nil #("q" 0 1 (ex-index 1)) nil))
  evil-ex-execute(#("q" 0 1 (ex-index 1)))
  evil-ex(nil)
  funcall-interactively(evil-ex nil)
  call-interactively(evil-ex nil nil)
  command-execute(evil-ex)
```

Why does adding the `save-current-session` function not ask for user input when it's added to the `kill-emacs-hook` but when calling it through M-x it does ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add-hook` is for *normal* hooks. Normal hooks are functions that accept no arguments, that is, you can call them with no args (and that's how they're called as hook functions).

But your function has a required argument - it *cannot* be called with no args.

The error message is telling you that it's called with one argument but it expects zero arguments.

---

Try this instead:

```lisp
(defun save-current-session ()
  (when (y-or-n-p "Do you want to save this session for later? ")
    (persp-state-save "~/.emacs.d/persp-state-file")))

(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'save-current-session)
```